# Finding the right place and storing in LinkedList

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list

I am trying to store the strings in a LinkedList. I am not allowed to pre-sort, but find the place and pass the string to the linked list. When i pass the strings through text file, the string do not go through the last else condition.
My input file has 
joe
appy
appz
zebra
cat

When it reaches appz, it doesn't go through any statement. It is supposed to insert the last else condition and print 5, but doesn't do that.

```
/**
     * Gets the string and arranges them in order
     * @param newString
     */
    public void store(String newString) {

        LinkedListNode current = head;
        System.out.println(newString);

        // if no element in the list
        if (current==null){
            System.out.println("1");
            makeNode(newString);
        }

        // if only 1 elements in the list
        else if(current.getNext()==null ){
            System.out.println("2");
            if(newString.compareTo(current.getName())<0){
                insertBefore(current.getName(),newString);
            } else{
                insertAfter(current.getName(),newString);
            }
        }

        // if the element is smaller than the head in the list
        else if(newString.compareTo(current.getName()) < 0){
            System.out.println("3");
            LinkedListNode temp = makeNode(newString);
            temp.setNext(current);
            head=temp;
        }

        // if the element is greater than the tail in the list
        else if(newString.compareTo(findTail().getName()) > 0){
            System.out.println("4");
            insertAfter(findTail().getName(),newString);
        }

        // for more than two elements in the list
        else{
            System.out.println("5");
            while(!(newString.compareTo(current.getName())>0  && newString.compareTo(current.getNext().getName())<0 ) && current.getNext()!=null){
                current=current.getNext();
            }

            if(newString.compareTo(current.getName())<0){
                insertBefore(current.getName(),newString);
            }
            else{
                insertAfter(current.getName(),newString);
            }
        }

    }   // end of store()
```

Comment: Does only appz have this problem or is it everything from appz and later? It looks like the last else condition should execute if none of the previous conditions execute. So anyway you look at it, it should print out one number - correct?

Comment: @Sunil: ya suil, i should go to the last statement at least, but just stops before printing 5, however the program keeps on running. Freezes right at the spot of appz.

Comment: Hmm. interesting. Since I don't have all the code, I need you to place breakpoints in every line from the first if (line with if(current == null)) till the last else (the one above the line that prints 5). Debug the program and can you let me know at which line the program stops? If everything is correct, it should go all the way to the last else but apparently that is not happening. Let me know which line or can you dump all the code somewhere and I can look at it

Comment: @Sunil: tried with the debugging but it didn't go through the last part. I am providing you link to the class files.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/gt1bzTAx    http://pastebin.com/suSS6ist    http://pastebin.com/1Gh3AQvr

Comment: cool.. I'll take a look at it in the evening. I'm kind of caught up with work right now but I did take a quick look and looks like you are using your own custom LinkedList(?)

Comment: @Sunil: I prefer to use my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some issue with the insertBefore. I updated it.

```
public void insertBefore(String later, String name){
        if(head==null){
            head = new LinkedListNode(name,null);
        }
        else if(head.getName()==later){
            LinkedListNode newNode = makeNode(name);
            newNode.setNext(head);
            head=newNode;   
        }
        else{
            LinkedListNode current = head;
            while(current.getNext().getName()!=later){
                current=current.getNext();
            }
            LinkedListNode newNode = makeNode(name); // create the new node
            newNode.setNext(current.getNext());    
            current.setNext(newNode);
        }
    } // end of insertBefore()
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I had forgotten to make the new node, instead changed the head.

Answer (score -1):

When you are traversing, you are not supposed to change the head reference. To traverse, simply do this:

```
Node tmp = head;
while(tmp != null) tmp = tmp.next;
```

This will become very handy to figure out where to insert new nodes or where to go to remove existing nodes.

Your class should also have methods to addFirst, addLast, insertBefore, insertAfter. In the code below, Object is whatever data type your need (in your case, String)

```
public void addLast(Object item)
{
  if(head == null)
  {
    addFirst(item);
  }
  else
  {
    Node<Object> tmp = head;
    while(tmp.next != null)
    {
      tmp = tmp.next;
    }
    tmp.next = new Node<Object>(item, null);
  }
}

public void addFirst(Object item)
{
  head = new Node<Object>(item, head);
}

public void insertAfter(Object key, Object item)
{
  Node<Object> tmp = head;
  while(tmp != null && !tmp.data.equals(key))
  {
    tmp = tmp.next;
  }

  if(tmp != null)
  {
    tmp.next = new Node<Object>(item, tmp.next);
  }
}

public void insertBefore(Object key, Object item)
{
  if(head == null)
  {
    return null;
  }

  if(head.data.equals(key))
  {
    addFirst(item);
    return;
  }

  Node<Object> previous = null;
  Node<Object> current = head;

  while(current != null && !current.data.equals(key))
  {
    previous = current;
    current = current.next;
  }

  //insert between current and previous
  if(current != null)
  {
    previous.next = new Node<Object>(item, current);
  }
}
```

In my opinion, you should not have a nested if/else construct to figure out where to insert. That should be up to the method you are invoking.

Secondly, the conditions you are using to control the flow of execution in your code are disparate.  Your IF condition is if the list is empty. If it is, create a new node and add it to the list.  That condition is followed by checking for a list containing only one node.  After that, you are not checking for the length of the list. The expected logic is that you should be checking for a list size greater than one; and yet this is your fall through case (the last else).  If you are going to be doing that kind of check outside the insert methods, then do something like this (stubbing your code):

```
if (current==null){
    System.out.println("1");
    makeNode(newString);
}

// if only 1 elements in the list
else if(current.getNext()==null ){
    System.out.println("2");
    if(newString.compareTo(current.getName())<0){
        insertBefore(current.getName(),newString);
    } else{
        insertAfter(current.getName(),newString);
    }
}

// if the list has more than one element
else
{
    // figure out where it goes (before or after) and insert
}
```

If you notice, the else/if and else blocks do basically the same thing.  Therefore, your code can (and should) be simplified as follows:

```
if (current==null){
    System.out.println("1");
    makeNode(newString);
}

// if the list has one or more elements
else
{
    // figure out where it goes (before or after) and insert
}
```